# Login popup error in new iOS 7 simulator could not validate user credentials

Tags: ios, ipad, ios6, authentication, ios7

I have been trying to make this login module which was created in iOS 6.0 work in iOS 7.0, but I am getting a lot of errors. I tried using `alert.alertViewStyle = UIAlertViewStyleLoginAndPasswordInput;`. But I can't really think of any way to resolve this issue. Please someone help me make this code work. Here is my current code.

I am getting following error
"libobjc.A.dylib`-[NSObject performSelector:withObject:withObject:]:"
also
"libdispatch.dylib`_dispatch_mgr_thread:"

```
    NSString *message = [[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:@"Login\n\n\n"];

    UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc]
                          initWithTitle: @"Enter user ID and password"
                          message: message
                          delegate: self
                          cancelButtonTitle: @"Cancel"
                          otherButtonTitles: @"OK", nil];

    alert.alertViewStyle = UIAlertViewStyleLoginAndPasswordInput;

    idField = [alert textFieldAtIndex:0];
    passwordField = [alert textFieldAtIndex:1];

   NSLog(@"idField: %@\npasswordField: %@", idField.text, passwordField.text);

    [alert addSubview:idField];
    [idField becomeFirstResponder];
    [alert addSubview:passwordField];
    [passwordField becomeFirstResponder];

    //UITextField *idField = [alert textFieldAtIndex:0];
   // UITextField *passwordField = [alert textFieldAtIndex:1];

  //  UITextField *_textField = [message textFieldAtIndex:0];

    /*   commented by Uday Kanike
    UITextField *text = [alert textFieldAtIndex:0];
    idField = text;
    [alert setDelegate:self];
    [alert setTitle:@"Entry User Name..."];
    [alert setMessage:@""];
    [alert addButtonWithTitle:@"Cancel"];
    [alert addButtonWithTitle:@"OK"];

    [idField setPlaceholder:@"Entry User Name..."];
    idField.autocapitalizationType = UITextAutocapitalizationTypeWords;
    idField.autocorrectionType = UITextAutocorrectionTypeNo;
    [alert addSubview:idField];
    [alert show];
    [idField becomeFirstResponder];


    UITextField *text1 = [alert textFieldAtIndex:1];
    passwordField = text1;
    [alert setDelegate:self];
    [alert setTitle:@"Entry Password..."];
    [alert setMessage:@""];
    [alert addButtonWithTitle:@"Cancel"];
    [alert addButtonWithTitle:@"OK"];

    [passwordField setPlaceholder:@"Entry Password..."];
    [alert addSubview:passwordField];
//    idField.autocapitalizationType = UITextAutocapitalizationTypeWords;
//    idField.autocorrectionType = UITextAutocorrectionTypeNo;

    [alert show];
    [passwordField becomeFirstResponder];

    [alert release];
    [idField release];
    [passwordField release];
    */
 //   NSString *title = [alert buttonTitleAtIndex:12];
 //   if([title isEqualToString:@"Login"])
 //   {
 //       UITextField *username = [alert textFieldAtIndex:0];
 //       UITextField *password = [alert textFieldAtIndex:1];
 //       NSLog(@"Username: %@\nPassword: %@", username.text, password.text);
 //   }

    /*UILabel *passwordLabel = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(12,40,260,25)];
    passwordLabel.font = [UIFont systemFontOfSize:16];
    passwordLabel.textColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
    passwordLabel.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
    passwordLabel.shadowColor = [UIColor blackColor];
    passwordLabel.shadowOffset = CGSizeMake(0,-1);
    passwordLabel.textAlignment = UITextAlignmentCenter;
    [alert addSubview:passwordLabel];
    [passwordLabel release];

    UIImageView *passwordImage = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage imageWithContentsOfFile:[[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"passwordfield" ofType:@"png"]]];
    passwordImage.frame = CGRectMake(11,79,262,31);
    [alert addSubview:passwordImage];
    [passwordImage release];

    UIImageView *passwordImage2 = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage imageWithContentsOfFile:[[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"passwordfield" ofType:@"png"]]];
    passwordImage2.frame = CGRectMake(11,44,262,31);
    [alert addSubview:passwordImage2];
    [passwordImage2 release];*/


    /*
    idField = [[UITextField alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(16,48,252,25)];
    idField.font = [UIFont systemFontOfSize:18];
    idField.backgroundColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
    idField.secureTextEntry = NO;
    idField.placeholder = @"User ID";
    idField.keyboardAppearance = UIKeyboardAppearanceDefault;
    [alert addSubview:idField];
    [idField becomeFirstResponder];

    passwordField = [[UITextField alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(16,83,252,25)];
    passwordField.font = [UIFont systemFontOfSize:18];
    passwordField.backgroundColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
    passwordField.secureTextEntry = YES;
    passwordField.placeholder = @"Password";
    passwordField.keyboardAppearance = UIKeyboardAppearanceAlert;
  //  passwordField.delegate = self;

    alert.delegate = self;
    alert.tag = 200;
    [alert addSubview:passwordField];

     [passwordField becomeFirstResponder];
    */
    idField.text = [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] objectForKey:@"SUPUserID"];
    passwordField.text = [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] objectForKey:@"SUPUserPassword"];

    RequestHandler *request = [RequestHandler uniqueInstance];
    [request unregisterUser];

    //[alert setTransform:CGAffineTransformMakeTranslation(0,0)];

    [alert show];
    [alert release];
    [message release];
```

Comment: Why are you using `[alert release]; [message release];`in ARC?

Comment: What errors are you getting?

Comment: I did tried commenting [alert release]; [message release];.

Comment: but it dint work. I am beginner so, all i am looking for is to validate the user id and password in this code. please help me with any alternate solution.

Comment: Please someone help me with some code.

Answer (score 1):

Try with bellow code, it is working fine.

```
 -(void)showLoginView
 {
      NSString *message = [[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:@"Login"];

      UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc]initWithTitle: @"Enter user ID and password"   message: message delegate: self cancelButtonTitle: @"Cancel" otherButtonTitles: @"OK", nil];
     alert.alertViewStyle = UIAlertViewStyleLoginAndPasswordInput;
     [alert setTag:111];
     [alert show];

     idField = [alert textFieldAtIndex:0];
     passwordField = [alert textFieldAtIndex:1]; 

     idField.text = [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] objectForKey:@"SUPUserID"];
     passwordField.text = [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] objectForKey:@"SUPUserPassword"];
  }

 -(void)alertView:(UIAlertView *)alertView clickedButtonAtIndex:(NSInteger)buttonIndex
 {
     if(alertView.tag == 111)
    {
        NSLog(@"idField: %@\npasswordField: %@", idField.text, passwordField.text);

    }
 }
```